# URL Scheme not trigger application:openURL:options

Tags: ios, deep-linking, url-scheme

I just setup my URL Scheme In `plist.info`file.

When I use the assoicated web page I have two different cases :

1 - If the app is lunched and in the background : The URL form the web page open the app and trigger `application:openURL:options` and the parameters parsed and the flow continue smoothly.

2 - If the app isn't lunched : The URL from the web page open the app but **NOT** trigger `application:openURL:options` so the application stop on the first screen.

Why the second scenario happened ? 
I'm on iOS 9.0 as a deployment target and iOS 9.3.5 as a testing device version.

Comment: Do you have read the discussion section in the docs? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=objc

Comment: That was the issue ! Thank you so much

Comment: @macmoonshine if you want to post it as answer I'll be happy to mark it as the right answer

Comment: I've added an adapted answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `application:openURL:options:` depends on the result of  `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods, because you can handle the incoming urls always inside of these methods. Take a look into the discussion section in the docs for `UIApplicationDelegate` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=objc) for more details.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).